# How to use footer in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5, demo

I am new in joomla 1.5 and I think it's not use footer menu but I want write some text on footer.So please tell me how this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

its easy to implement .i have already done in my site.i have used this [Module](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/content-embed/7528) for that purpose.

Steps:-

1.Create your Article (write your text)path-->your domin/administrator-->content-->Article Manager -->New Article

2.Install that modules .

3.give your Article id into that module parameter .

4.Set module on the "footer" position.
Now you got result.

All The Best...
With Regards,
R.Ram kumar.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a custom HTML module, insert your content in there and then put that module on the "footer" position.